# How to set UITabBarController to View?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

I have an app that have several views. In one view I would like to add a `UITabBarController`.

In another app I used this to add the `UITabBarController` to the `rootViewController`, but I am not sure if that is even the correct way to do it.

in the .h

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITabBarController *tabBarController;
```

in the .m

```
@synthesize tabBarController=_tabBarController;
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
```

Comment: if you need to add tab bar for one view then use UITabBar not UITabBarController.

Comment: One can not add a UITabBarController to a view.

Comment: you want to add tab bar in between app or at root?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In one of my app i have used this code to set tabbarcontroller in between app

define tabbar controller in AppDelegate.m

```
self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
self.tabBarController.delegate=self;
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex=0;
self.tabBarController.delegate=self;


- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController{
//NSUInteger index=[[tabBarController viewControllers] indexOfObject:viewController];

  // return YES;
}
```

Apply below code where you want to push your controller with tab bar controller

```
AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    UIViewController *viewController1 = [[GeneralViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GeneralViewController" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *viewController2 = [[MiscQuotationController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MiscQuotationController" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *viewController4 = [[QuotationListController alloc] initWithNibName:@"QuotationListController" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *viewController5 = [[ChargesViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ChargesViewController" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *viewController7 = [[SalesPartViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SalesPartViewController" bundle:nil];

    ///   tab button title
    viewController1.title = @"Basic information";
    viewController2.title = @"Misc Quotation";
    viewController4.title = @"Quotation Line";
    viewController5.title = @"Charges";
    viewController7.title = @"Sales Part Stock";

    // tab button Images
    viewController1.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"general.png"];
    viewController2.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"misle.png"];
    viewController4.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"history.png"];
    viewController5.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"charges.png"];
    viewController7.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"shoebox.png"];

    delegate.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    delegate.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;
    delegate.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController1, viewController2, viewController4, viewController5, viewController7, nil];
    delegate.tabBarController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:delegate.tabBarController animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing this

`self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;`

Write this in the code:

`[self.window addSubview:self.tabBarController.view];`

You cannot add `UITabbarController` to `UIViewController`, but you can add `UITabBar` to `UIViewController's` view.

Hope this might help you.......

Comment: Well, the "self.window" is the issue. How do I access this on a UIViewController?

Comment: using the object of your AppDelegate class....... Also the TabbarController is to be declared in the AppDelegate class.