# How to customize UITABBAR IOS 5.0?

Tags: ios5, uitabbaritem

I have to customize the images in tabbar items for insert an image in my icon, how can I do?
I heard from my friend that I should create a new xib and work it to do a new tabbar item customized .
Is it true?

thanks a lot!

Comment: have a look at these samples for custom tabbar items

Comment: check out the answer here it's may be your solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9976839/how-to-set-uitabbarcontroller-to-view/9977322#9977322

Answer (score 0):

just put the below method in

> appdelegate.m

File

```
- (void)customizeAppearance

{

// Costomise UITabBar   

// Note you can also specify “finished” and “unfinished” images if you wish to modify the manner in which the selected & unselected images appear.

UIImage *tabBackground = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab_bg"]resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];

[[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:tabBackground];

[[UITabBar appearance] setSelectionIndicatorImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab_select_indicator"]];

}
```

this may help you
 [Please find much more on this site](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4344/user-interface-customization-in-ios-5)